# Why does Camel noErrorHandler log warning message with stack trace?

Tags: java, error-handling, apache-camel

We are using Camel 2.15.4 to connect our Swing clients to our OSGi server.

In the server, under certain circumstances, we throw a sub-class of `RuntimeException` which we want to propagate back to the client.

In the building of our routes we are using:

```
errorHandler(noErrorHandler());
```

But every time we throw one of these server errors, we get a WARN log message with a full stack trace. The testers are finding these log messages rather unnerving as they look like problems.

Is there any way to switch off the logging of these warnings?

Here's an example:

```
16:37:12,565 | WARN  | che.camel.camel-core | Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException]
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: xxxxxx.yyyyyyy.exceptions.CustomException: blah
at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1619)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanInvocation.invoke(BeanInvocation.java:87)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:134)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:68)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProducer.process(BeanProducer.java:38)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:129)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:91)
at uniworks.camel.interceptor.CamelInterceptor$1.process(CamelInterceptor.java:79)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:91)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:103)[58:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.15.4]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:569)[176:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:507)[176:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:474)[176:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)[176:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)[176:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1103)[176:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1095)[176:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:992)[176:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_92]
```

In the previous version of our server, which used Camel 2.11.0 and Spring DSL, we defined our route contexts with:

```
<camel:errorHandler id="noErrorHandler" type="NoErrorHandler"/>

<camel:camelContext id="blah_camel" errorHandlerRef="noErrorHandler">
    .....
```

and we did not get these warning log messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is actually not Camel's no error handler doing this logging but the JMS component. The JMS component has some fallback logging of exceptions to indicate the JMS message was not processeed successfully. You can see the two options: `errorHandlerLoggingLevel` and `errorHandlerLogStackTrace` on the JMS component/endpoint which you can turn off/configure: http://camel.apache.org/jms

Comment: Thanks Claus. I see that there is also a `setErrorHandlerLogStackTrace(false)` method on the `JmsComponent` class.